# Geofirestore get subcollections from geo collection in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, geofirestore

I would like to retrieve the subcollections by making my request with geofirestore, like so:

[image: My firestore]

[image]

The id of each PRODUCTS corresponds to that of the user who created new products (for the moment there is only one).

That's my code right now:

```
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';
import * as geofirestore from 'geofirestore';

const firestoreApp = firestore();
const GeoFirestore = geofirestore.initializeApp(firestoreApp);
const geocollection = GeoFirestore.collection('PRODUCTS');

const query = geocollection.limit(30).near({
  center: new firestore.GeoPoint(coords.latitude, coords.longitude),
  radius: 1000,
});

try {
  query.onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
    const productsQueried = querySnapshot.docs.reduce(
      (result, documentSnapshot) => {
        console.log(documentSnapshot);
        if (documentSnapshot.id !== user.uid) {
          result.push(documentSnapshot.data());
        }
        return result;
      },
      []
    );
    setListOfProducts(productsQueried);
    console.log(productsQueried);
    setLoading(false);
  });
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

Of course, I can only find the geocollection, but cannot access the 'USER_PRODUCTS' collection inside.
*{exists: true, id: "OUJ6r3aF9nVfgtfkQRES7kpYCko1", distance: 0, data: ƒ}*

The final goal is to retrieve a list of products for each close customer and then sort so as not to retrieve that of the current user.

Do I necessarily have to make a second request (can I do it in one?) Or do I have to change the way I save the product lists of different users in firestore?

Comment: Have you seen [collection group](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) queries? These allow you to query across subcollections.

Comment: Yes, but cannot find the way of making it works with my current code.

Comment: Can you provide a better output of what you data structure looks like with the subcollections etc?

Comment: I edited my post and added another picture so you can see the rest of my data structure.
But it something like so: PRODUCTS(list of users'stores) => doc(using id of user) => USER_PRODUCTS(list of all the products created within the user's store) => doc, doc... (list of products from the selected user)